# fs.defaultFS only listens to localhost's port 8020

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have a CDH4.3 all-in-one vm up and running, i am trying to install a hadoop client remotely. I noticed that, without changing any default settings, my hadoop cluster is listening to `127.0.0.1:8020`.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ netstat -lent | grep 8020
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      492        100202 

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ telnet ${all-in-one vm external IP} 8020
Trying ${all-in-one vm external IP}...
telnet: connect to address ${all-in-one vm external IP} Connection refused
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8020
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'
```

my remote machine has all the configuration(`core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml`) pointing to the `${all-in-one vm external IP}`. When I run something from the remote client and I get this:

```
└ $ ./bin/hdfs --config /home/${myself}/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/etc/hadoop dfs -ls
13/10/27 05:27:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to ${all-in-one vm external IP}:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I changed my hadoop all-in-one vm:
`core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml`  under `/etc/hadoop/conf` from:`localhost.localdomain` -> `${all-in-one vm external IP},` but after restarting hdfs, it still listens to localhost 8020. any ideas? How can I make it listen to ${external IP} on 8020 instead of localhost.

Comment: hmmm... this seems old, but I see the same issue using hadoop 2.7.3.  Changing the port core-site.xml does nothing and if a value is anything other than 8020, results in connections being refused from `hdfs://myserver/`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to directly tweak the property `dfs.namenode.rpc-address` to be `0.0.0.0:8020` to make the NameNode Client IPC service listen on all interfaces, or set it to your specific IP to only make it listen there.

That said, the `all-in-one vm external IP` change you state should have worked, but since the question does not have your exact configurations and logs, I cannot tell why.